# Plugin for vim that auto indents after a : when editing python?

Tags: filetype-python

Is there a way to indent automatcally after typing a : when editing python in vim?  I works that way in CodeMirror and I found it nice; so I wondered if vim has that capability?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try adding the following lines to your `.vimrc`:

```
syntax on
filetype plugin indent on
```

*N.B. The `plugin` is not necessary for indenting, but it enables filetype plugins to run, which you probably want.*

This will cause Vim to load its Python indent script when you edit a Python file, which will set the following option:

```
:set indentexpr=GetPythonIndent(v:lnum)
```

This will cause Vim to use an automatic indent on lines after statements that end in `:` characters.

If you'd like to see how this works, you can view the indent script with the command:

```
:e $VIMRUNTIME/indent/python.vim
```

See `:h :filetype-indent-on` and `:h indent-expressions` for more details.

If you find Vim's included indent file insufficient for your needs, [you might like to try this plugin](https://github.com/Vimjas/vim-python-pep8-indent.git), which offers a few refinements over the built-in version: this is what I'm currently using for Python indenting.